# More efficient countdown routine? [.BAT]

Tags: batch-file, countdown

I'm trying to run a script that counts down from 60:00, where 60 is the number of seconds and 00 the number of milliseconds. I can't get the script to function properly at all. Anyone have any idea on what's the problem?

```
:PhaseTwo
Set /a bignum=60
Set smallnum=00
Set /a handlevariable=1
Set /a bignumhandle=0
ping localhost -n 2 >nul

:StopWatchRoutine
If %bignum% EQU 00 GoTo :StopWatchEndCheck
:StopWatchEndCheckNo
If %bignum% EQU 9 set /a bignumhandle=1
If %smallnum% EQU 9 set /a handlevariable=1
If %handlevariable% EQU 1 GoTo :NumberMods
Set /a smallnum-=1
GoTo :StopWatchHandle

:StopWatchEndCheck
If %smallnum% EQU 01 GoTo :StopWatchExit
GoTo :StopWatchEndCheckNo

:NumberMods
If %smallnum% EQU 00 set /a smallnum=99
If %smallnum% EQU 00 set /a handlevariable=0
If %smallnum% EQU 01 set smallnum=00
If %smallnum% EQU 02 set smallnum=01
If %smallnum% EQU 03 set smallnum=02
If %smallnum% EQU 04 set smallnum=03
If %smallnum% EQU 05 set smallnum=04
If %smallnum% EQU 06 set smallnum=05
If %smallnum% EQU 07 set smallnum=06
If %smallnum% EQU 08 set smallnum=07
If %smallnum% EQU 09 set smallnum=08
If %smallnum% EQU 9 set smallnum=09
If %smallnum% EQU 99 set /a bignum-=1
If %bignumhandle% EQU 1 GoTo :BigNumMods
GoTo :StopWatchHandle

:BigNumMods
If %bignum% EQU 01 set bignum=00
If %bignum% EQU 02 set bignum=01
If %bignum% EQU 03 set bignum=02
If %bignum% EQU 04 set bignum=03
If %bignum% EQU 05 set bignum=04
If %bignum% EQU 06 set bignum=05
If %bignum% EQU 07 set bignum=06
If %bignum% EQU 08 set bignum=07
If %bignum% EQU 09 set bignum=08
If %bignum% EQU 9 set bignum=09


:StopWatchHandle 
cls
echo Program Launch Console, Version 1.0.2
echo.
echo StopWatch: %bignum%:%smallnum%
echo.
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
GoTo :StopWatchRoutine

:StopWatchExit
echo.
GoTo :PhaseThree
```

I'm using this batch file as part of a user interface, so it is important that the echo part of it stays intact. Otherwise, any suggestions on how to make the script more efficient are welcome.

Thank you for all your assistance, it's very, VERY much appreciated.

Comment: You are stating numbers with preceding `0`, which causes `IF ... EQU ...` to interprete them as octal numbers rather than decimal ones. Furthermore, you should use `set /A` which is capable of performing maths...

Comment: Usually when we talk about seconds and milliseconds, we format it as `ss.SSS`, not `ss:SS`.

Comment: `powershell "$t = (get-date).addSeconds(60); while ((get-date) -lt $t) {(write-host -nonewline \`r($t - (get-date)).totalseconds\`t)};write-host -nonewline \`rDone.\`t\`t\`r\`n"`

Comment: @aschipfl Okay, so how do I solve this problem? I am using set /a above, as well.

Comment: @shoover I have a reason for the special formatting, but I do understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @rojo How do I echo this to the screen?

Comment: Enclose both `IF ... EQU ...` expressions in double-quotes, then the comparison is done literally. Yes, you are using `SET /A` occasionally but you are also doing decrements (`-1`) in `:NumberMods` and `:BigNumMods` blocks with tons of `IF`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me. A couple comments first:

- I dont' like questions that state: "Hey, my code don't works. Please review it and fix the problem". You should *explain* what the code is supposed to do and what it really does.
- I think you have a couple confusions here, starting with "and 00 the number of milliseconds" (milliseconds have 3 digits, centiseconds 2). If you want that the program refresh the screen *as fast as possible* (in order to show elapsed milliseconds, or centiseconds), why do you use `ping` command? Its effect is precisely the opposite to the desired one!

Anyway, if you want a more efficient countdown routine in Batch, try this one:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


:PhaseTwo

rem Get a CR control character (Ascii 13)
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

cls
echo Program Launch Console, Version 1.0.2
echo.
set /P "=StopWatch: 60.000!CR!" < NUL

set /A bignum=60, smallnum=2000
for /F "tokens=3 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do set "currentSec=%%a"

:StopWatchRoutine
for /F "tokens=3 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do if "%currentSec%" equ "%%a" (
   set /A smallnum-=4
) else (
   rem The next line will help to adjust previous smallnum's subtrahend
   REM ECHO/
   set "currentSec=%%a"
   set /A bignum-=1, smallnum=2000
   if !bignum! equ 0 goto StopWatchExit
)

:StopWatchHandle 
set /P "=StopWatch: %bignum%:%smallnum:~1% !CR!" < NUL
GoTo :StopWatchRoutine

:StopWatchExit
echo StopWatch: 0.000
echo/
echo.
```

Note that, in order to display the milliseconds in a way as realist as possible, you must adjust the number in `set /A smallnum-=4` command. The "4" is the right one for my computer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry, I'm just learning batch code and indeed was confused about a few things. As far as the purpose of the code, it's meant to provide a delay of 60 seconds to allow several minimized batch windows to run checks that will modify operations later in this script.